# How to create a pop-up login/register?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am new, so tutorials/book recommendations would be excellent. I am looking to create a pop-up login/register similar to these sites below:

http://www.pacsun.com/

http://www.sears.com/

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/

I also would appreciate the name of what it is called.

Comment: Wow... this is about as general of a question as, "how do I create google".

Comment: @SeanStopnik Not really -- OP has a specific question ("what's the name for x?") which has a specific answer ("modal").

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Actually his question, right in the title, is 'how do I create a pop up login". Telling him it's called a modal really doesn't answer that. But it looks like he's happy with that, so...

Comment: @SeanStopnik Did you read the post? The title is a misnomer.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Did you read the post?? The key word is ALSO. To quote, 'I also would appreciate the name of what it is called. '. ALSO implies it's, at the very least, a second question... But not the original question. Which again.. Is in the title. But like I said.. He's happy.

Comment: @SeanStopnik "tutorials/book recommendations would be excellent."

Comment: @kittykittybangbang I wasn't answering the question... I was just commenting on it. But feel free to suggest some resources for him to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You may use magnific popup, it's easily customize and it's have lot's of features. If you don't want to lot of features then you can build your own magnific popup js 
easyly

Documentation:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

One option is magnific popup.

[Magnific popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)

Another option is Avgrund.js

[Avgrund.js](http://lab.hakim.se/avgrund/)

However, if you really want to do it on you own without external sources, then create a div with all the options. Then style it using css, and set visibility to invisible.
Finally, using jquery, make it visible on button click.